# C++ resource syntax error

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, resources, rc

I have a resource:

```
IDC_MYMENU MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "E&xit"
    END
    POPUP "&Stuff"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&Go"
    END
END
```

On the first END it says there is a syntax error, I don't understand why. Anyone know? :(

Comment: Have you `#defined` END?

Comment: Now it says the there is an error at the 2nd POPUP

Comment: :), No I mean maybe you defined it so it was substituted for something so it triggers a syntax error. Try appending `, ID_CONTROL` on the `MENUITEM` line.

Comment: MENUITEM "E&xit", ID_CONTROL ?

Comment: Yes. But you should define ID_CONTROL to some numeric value. Why don't you use the resource editor? It does this automatically.

Comment: ISTR the express versions of VC++ not supporting GUI resource editing.  The resource script has to be edited manually in Express by right clicking and picking "View code".

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++, so you might want to change the title of your question.  The tags look good.

Comment: Well, I've created the GUI using like C++ and I am now trying to add a menu >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you haven't set the ID for the MENUITEM. The resource compiler expects additional parameter after the string. See documentation here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381025%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need an ID associated with a menu item, something like:

```
#include "resources.h"
#include "windows.h"

IDC_MYMENU MENU
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "E&xit", ID_EXIT
    END
    POPUP "&Stuff"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&Go", ID_GO
    END
END
```

where resources.h would look something like:

```
#define ID_GO 101
```

[At east if memory serves, ID_EXIT will normally be pre-defined by Windows.h, so you don't need to define it.]

The ID is the value that your program will receive in the WM_COMMAND message when that menu item is selected. The values are (virtually always) in a separate header for you to include in both the RC file and your code to ensure against any mismatches.